# Rsyslog + Virtualenv

Tags: python, centos, virtualenv, rsyslog

I'm using a shell execute action in rsyslog to a python script on a CentOS machine.  How can I ensure that it runs in a specified virtualenv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you ever asked a question while researching something, then learned what you needed to do and then wished you hadn't asked the question?

All you need to do is modify your python path and add the path to the site-packages directory of the virtualenv you want to use.

Comment: However, good on you for coming back, months later, and publicly posting the answer to the question that you yourself asked!